# SFDX Permission set Overwrite during SFDX Deployment

Tags: salesforcedx

We are deploying one permission set with SFDX which already has permission to multiple Object in the Org. In the permission set XML file, we have only changed Object permission. But when We deploy the permission set with SFDX, It is removing the existing permission from the Custom Object which was not mention in the Permission set XML File. As per the below URL it should only update the permission defined in the XML file

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_permissionset.htm

Answer (score 1):

Ever since v40.0 or so, Permission Sets have been considered entire units. If you want the older non-destructive-update behavior, you need to use v39.0 or lower, such as the Ant Toolkit. This change is also why retrieving an Permission Set always retrieves all permissions now, because it makes it easier to merge in new changes.